# to believe an advice vs to believe in an advice

Tags: meaning, verbs

I know that "to believe" means "to think that to something is true or correct" when used with things. (references: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/believe , https://www.wordreference.com/definition/believe ).

What does "to believe an advice from somebody" mean? Thinking that an advice is true or correct does not make much sense to me. Does it mean "to think that the advice is good and worthwhile to follow"? If so, couldn't I also say "to believe in an advice", given that "to believe in" can mean the same, eg I believe in getting to work early (according to https://www.wordreference.com/definition/believe) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advice is correct if it is good advice that helps you.  If you believe some advice, then you believe the advice is good for you.

> He advised me to quit my job, and I believed his advice. But now I have no money. I should not have taken the advice.

You can say "I believed in his advice".  You can't say "I believed in an advice" because "advice" is (nearly always) uncountable.  It may be better to say "I believed him"

> He advised me to quit my job and I believed him.

Comment: Is there any difference in meaning between "to believe his advice" and "to believe in his advice" ?

Comment: A little difference of nuance.  "Believed in" suggests a matter of faith: believing without evidence.  I'd suppose "believe his advice" is more common, since you aren't suggesting a matter of faith.